# laravel 5 exception Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException in unit test

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to write a test that check some activities done only with registered users. so I need to pass through the laravel 5 authentication process (with `_token)`

this is my test class

```
    class ImportTest extends TestCase {

            private $files = array();
            /**
             * Creates the application.

         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
         */
        public function createApplication()
        {
                $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

                $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->bootstrap();

                return $app;
        }

        private function beTheUser(){

            $this->be(User::all()->first());
        }


        public function testAccessImportPageAjaxLoggedIn(){
            $this->beTheUser();
            $import = Import::all()->first();
            if($import!=null){
                $this->call('POST','ImportDocumentsController@status',array(
                    'import_id' => $import->id,
                    '_token' => Session::token()
                ));
                $this->assertResponseStatus('404');
            }


            $this->assertTrue(TRUE);
        }
}
```

and when I try to test the function with phpunit test, I got testing.ERROR: `exception Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException`

anybody know a workaround?

Comment: Try adding `Session::start()` in the `setUp()` method.

Answer (score 2):

one possible solution, as @lukasgeiter spotted, is to write this line

```
        public function beTheUser {
            Session::start();
            $this->be(User::all()->first());

        }
```

I also needed to add this line at the beginning of the file.

```
use Session;
```

and not
use `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;`

then
when needed in the function...

```
        $this->call('POST','/documents/import/'.$import->id,array(
            '_token' => Session::get('_token')
        ));
//or 


        $this->call('POST','/documents/import/'.$import->id,array(
            '_token' => Session::token()
        ));
```

Comment: You can use `Session::token()` though

Answer (score 2):

Run `php artisan config:clear`. Your config could be cached causing the test env to actually be pointing to your local environment

Relevant Laracasts thread: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravelphpunit-testing-tokenmismatchexception#reply=486865

Answer (score 0):

Try csrf_token() instead of Session::token().

Comment: `csrf_token()` just calls `app('session')->token()`